# create a single String variable out of multiple random character variables

Tags: java, string

I want to generate a fixed amount of random random characters, and then save those characters to a String variable. Here is the simple 'for' loop I have written so far:

```
String listChars = "";

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    char randomChar = (char)((Math.random()*255)+32);
    System.out.print(randomChar);
    String listChars = "" + randomChar;
}

System.out.print(listChars);
```

I excluded the first 32 characters to avoid the control characters. My for loop prints 50 random characters to the screen just fine, but my `listChars` variable doesn't seem to be storing the values the way I want. (I want to store them as one 50 character long string)

Is there a way to make this work, perhaps with an array?

Comment: "storing the values the way I want"? what way you want?

Comment: There is no `listChars` variable. You mean `listWords`, right?

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder to concatenate your string (more efficient)

Comment: I want to store them as a String. Sorry I thought my question made that clear. I will make an edit.

Comment: Or a `char[]`, or a `CharBuffer`.

Comment: But you _can_ build a `String` from a `char[]` (or a `CharBuffer`)

Comment: My bad on the typo, my code said listWords but the variable should have been called listChars. I have been awake for too long it seems. I updated my OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a duplicated variable in the `for` loop.

This:

```
String listwords = "" + randomChar;
```

should be:

```
listwords += randomChar;
```

Comment: Thanks; this answer was short and sweet. And fast as hell.

Answer (score 2):

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        char randomChar = (char)((Math.random()*255)+32);
        System.out.print(randomChar);
        builder.append(randomChar);
    }
    System.out.print(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of `String` variable. They consumes less memory.

`StringBuilder` is better than `StringBuffer` in terms of memory but it is not thread safe.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
```

Try to use like this in your for loop

```
sb.append(randomChar);
```

Comment: Thank you for the memory saving advice. I'm not really concerned with memory usage in this project but I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String listwords = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        char randomChar = (char)((Math.random()*255)+32);
        System.out.print(randomChar);
        listwords += randomChar;
        }
        System.out.print(listwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String listwords = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    char randomChar = (char)((Math.random()*255)+32);
    System.out.print(randomChar);
    listwords = listwords + randomChar;
    }
    System.out.print(listwords);
```

Comment: please add some more information, such as explanation of how your code solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare new String variable `listwords` inside the loop .

Remove :-

```
String listwords = "" + randomChar;
```

Add :-

```
listwords = "" + randomChar;
```